# how to get text from an html paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I'm working on an SAPUI5 and using plain html within it in order to add more functionality. The thing is that I'm unable to grab the data from the `<p>` element. I get an undefined error. my goal is to use `<p>` with `contenteditable` so I can edit the data in it directly and add formatting to it at the same time.

Here is my attempt at putting an example together.

XMLView

```
<mvc:View
xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
height="100%"
xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
controllerName="sap.m.sample.Button.Page">

<Page class="sapUiContentPadding" >
    <content>
        <HBox>
            <Button type="Accept"
                    text="Accept"
                    press="onPress"
                    ariaDescribedBy="acceptButtonDescription genericButtonDescription">
                <layoutData>
                    <FlexItemData growFactor="1" />
                </layoutData>
            </Button>
        </HBox>
    </content>
    <FlexBox direction="Column" alignItems="Center">
        <html:div id="divcontainer">
            <html:p id="divcontent" contenteditable="true">something something</html:p>
        </html:div>
        <html:label id="mylabel">something label here</html:label>
        <html:p id="input" contenteditable="true">
                To break lines in a text,use the <html:br></html:br>  
            <html:i>element</html:i>
        </html:p>
    </FlexBox>
</Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Here is my controller, where I try to grab the data.

```
sap.ui.define(['sap/m/MessageToast','sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller'],
function(MessageToast, Controller) {
"use strict";

var PageController = Controller.extend("sap.m.sample.Button.Page", {

    onPress: function (evt) {

        var div = this.getView().byId("divcontainer");

        var inputText = document.getElementById("input").innerHtml;
        //var x = inputText.textContent ? inputText.textContent : inputText.innerText;

        //var text = inputText.innerHTML();
        console.log(input);
        console.log(div);
    }
});

return PageController;

 });
```

Comment: It should be `.innerHTML` not `.innerHtml`

Comment: good catch. That still didn't work: var inputA = this.getView().byId("input").innerHTML; gives me undefined. If I do only var inputA = this.getView().byId("input"); I can print the inputA with all its components but can't see anything related to the text inside it.

Comment: actually I figured it out. Since it's html within SAPUI5 I had to get the html reference to it before I can actually get the data.
var inputA = this.getView().byId("input").getDomRef();//.innerHTML;
 var x = inputA.innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

First off I am not super fond of the `input` id here but that is only my opinion.

`this.byId()` is within the current view `this.getView().byId()` useful for some element in some other view.

If you change your code to this I believe it will work according to my limited knowledge of this:

<s>var inputText = this.byId("input").innerHTML;</s> **WRONG :(**

```
var inputText = this.byId("input").content();

this.byId("input").setContent("<p>" + inputText + "</p>");// now wrapped in a paragraph
```

Beware of un-sanitized HTML regarding XSS here.

Also this may be better

```
this.getView().byId("input").setDOMContent(somedomcontent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can make use of jQuery because SAPUI5 has already implemented with
>   it.

Adding a class instead of id would do great for plain html in your case. Adding id would dynamically prefixed.

```
<html:p class="input" contenteditable="true">
     To break lines in a text,use the <html:br></html:br>  
     <html:i>element</html:i>
</html:p>
```

Inside onPress :

```
onPress: function (evt) {                       
             var inputText = $(".input").html()
             console.log(inputText);
        }
```